# JButton problems not showing up?

Tags: java, swing, authentication, jbutton, visibility

I have a simple JAVA game launcher that you can create accounts, and log into those accounts. when logged in, you have an option to log off, bringing you back to the main menu of the Launcher. That all works, but when you log in again, the button to log off is no longer there.
This is my log off code:

```
if (event.getSource().equals(logout)) {
    isLogin = false;
    UsRName = "";
    PaSSWord = "";
    logoff.setVisible(false);
    ps.setVisible(false);
    usrnm.setVisible(true);
    pswrd.setVisible(true);
    login.setText("Login");
    register.setText("Need an Account?");
    scroll.setVisible(true);
    usr.setText("Username:");
    ps.setText("Password:");
    ps.setVisible(true);
    usrnm.setText("");
    pswrd.setText("");
    System.out.println("done");
}
```

logoff is a JButton that logs you off. everything else is just to get the JFrame the way I want it to look.

```
isLogin = true;
logoff.add(logout);
logout.setVisible(true);
frame.add(logoff);
lastLogin.replace("*", "");
//set the logged in look!
usrnm.setVisible(false);
pswrd.setVisible(false);
login.setText("Start Game");
register.setText("Account Settings");
scroll.setVisible(false);
usr.setText("");
ps.setVisible(true);
if (lastLogin == "") {
    ps.setText("Welcome " + UsRName + "! You can Edit your Settings here.");
} else {
    ps.setText("Welcome back " + UsRName + "! You last loged in " + lastLogin);
}
```

This is my code for login in and setting the logoff button's visibility back. But when the event for loging in is called the button still doesn't show up.
any suggestions?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the visibility of `logoff` to `false` when you are logging off:

```
logoff.setVisible(false);
```

But you are setting visibility of `logout` to `true` when logging in:

```
logout.setVisible(true);
```

While still the visibility of `logoff` is `false`!

Comment: thank you so much!!! it works now. i can't believe i missed that! haha thank you!